# IE11: Обновить рендеринг страницы через JS?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

После подгрузки контента через ajax модального bootstrap окна и выполнения джава скриптов наблюдается ошибка графического рендеринга страницы в IE11 (в хроме и FF все нормально рисует), ошибка исчезает если выполнить в конце выполнения скриптов alert (видимо message box заставляет перерисовать IE11 графическое содержимое страницы заново).

Каким еще способом можно заставить перерисовать графическое содержимое страницы заново в IE11 через JS кроме использования alert?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте заметку Пола Айриша о том что может вызвать перерисовку страницы: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Вкратце суть в том, что нужно на body навесить какой-то класс. После этого произвести какое-либо измерение, например получить scrollTop и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Повесить и снять класс на `body`. Даже если этого класса нет в стилях. Желательно по таймеру с экспоненциальным интервалом несколько раз.

А вообще, странно, что такое есть в IE11 - я только в IE8 сталкивался. Стоит свой код получше проверить.

Comment: Проблема была в .ajaxStop по схеме: .load -> document.ready -> .ajax calls (async) -> .ajaxStop; Впечатление того что последний вызов по .ajaxStop отрабатывал раньше чем полностью завершился .load Тем не менее если привязываться к .ajax.done то все заработало корректно.